# Trying to understand dispatching

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to get my head around the dispatch mechanism of Objective-C. But don't succeed.

I have these two methods:

```
- (void)downloadImage
        {
            NSString * URLString= @"http://www.something.com";
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0),
                   ^{
                       NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
                       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
                       theImportant.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

                       dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                           stopAnimate=true;
                           [self MoveToPosition:myView.center];



                       });
                   });
}
```

and:

```
-(void)MoveToPosition:(CGPoint)position{
        NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut |UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                         animations:^{
                             myView.center=position;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             if (stopAnimate){
                                 //do Nothing
                             } else if (someFlag){
                                 [self downloadImage];
                             } 
                         }
         ];
}
```

So, the first method is called by the second, which in turn is calling the first.

This is working all fine, except for the fact that somehow **theImportant.image** is not displayed.

When I move the

```
theImportant.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

within the

```
dispatch_sync
```

block of **downloadImage**, the animation starts behaving in an unexpected way.

I do realize that I don't completely understand the dispatching, but I hope that your insights will grow my wisdom.

theImportant is defined as

**@property (strong, atomic) IBOutlet UIImageView * theImportant;**

My question in short is: why is my theImportant.image not displayed.

Comment: In order for us to help you with this issue you are going to need to post real code including the `aMethodThatNeedsVERYIMPORTANTImageToBeInPlaceInTime` method (the real method of course) as well as details about what `VERIMPORTANT` is and how it has been setup.

Comment: Added the other method

Comment: It's still really unclear what your code is doing, and what exactly "behaving in an unexpected way" means.  What kind of object is `theImportant`? What is its type?

Comment: please see my edits. In the code above, my animation is moving smoothly up to the point where the image is supposed to be shown. When I move "theImportant.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];" into the dispatch _sync block, somehow, it starts jumping.

Comment: It can take a significant amount of time for `[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]` to run. What happens if you do `UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];` outside the dispatch_sync, then do `theImportant.image = newImage;` inside the dispatch_sync? (The latter must happen on the main queue.)

Comment: Also, what is your view hierarchy? Is `theImportant` a subview of `myView`?  Is changing `theImportant`'s image also causing its size to change? Are you using auto layout for any of these views? etc.  There are a million reasons why this could go wrong, but since you haven't given us a reproducible case, we have to guess.

Comment: Your suggestion to first make the newImage didn't work. I tried to reduce the code to its essence. theImportant is managed by auto layout, but not resized. I wouldn't expect that to be relevant. I very much appreciate your involvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dispatch_xxx... methods do not *call* anything. They take a block of code and add it to a queue. It's the same as if you wrote some instructions on a piece of paper and put that piece of paper on the desk of a co-worker. Your co-worker will finish whatever he's been doing, and when he is done, he will do what is written on the paper.

There is one special queue, called the "global queue". If you put a piece of paper on the "global" desk, there are five dozen co-workers, and any of them could pick up that piece of paper at any time, so jobs will be done faster (because many people work on the different tasks) but you never know in which order they are done.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding

```
@property (strong, atomic)  UIImage * theImportantImage;
```

to my .h file, setting the image to that, and then I did

```
theImportantFace.image=theImportantImage.
```

Not sure why that would work, but hey, it does. It seems my problem was not related to async stuff at all. Pity. Unsatisfactory not to find out what is the issue.